# Mock Objects Created Inside method Under test to verify the arguments passed

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, jmockit

Have a method as follows -

```
Class A
{

public void methodA(String zipcode)

{

  Country c= new Country(zipcode) 

}

}
```

Is it possible to verify using JUnit, that the country object got created with argument zipcode.

The test method will be somethig like

```
@Test
public void testMethod()
{
  A a = new A();  
  a.methodA("testCode");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No you cannot do that without being able to access the created `Country` somehow to validate its values. However, you don't really need to since you test behavior, not data.

Comment: @daniu is correct, You don't need to test that. However, if it is that necessary, you can think of calling a callback function in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you do need to test the call (as opposed to only its effects, what you can do is introducing a factory method in the tested class.

```
Class A {
    private Function<String,Country> createCountry = Country::new;
    public void methodA(String zipcode) {
          Country c= createCountry.apply(zipCode);
    }
}
```

Which you can then mock.

```
class ATest {
    @InjectMocks A sut;
    @Mock Function<String,Country> creator;

    @Test public void testCountryCreated() {
        String zipcode = "1234";

        Country country = mock(Country.class);
        when(creator.apply(zipcode)).thenReturn(country);

        sut.methodA(zipcode);

        verify(creator).apply(zipcode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PowerMockito you can do it easily like [that](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(X.class)
public class XTest {
        @Test
        public void test() {
                whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new IOException("error message"));

                X x = new X();
                x.y(); // y is the method doing "new MyClass()"

                ..
        }
}
```

Use PowerMockito.verifyNew, e.g.

```
verifyNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments();
```

Comment: Interesting, never used PowerMockito. So do you have to do `whenNew(...)...` before you can use `verifyNew()`, so the constructor call gets mocked?

Comment: Exactly, PowerMockito has some new features such as you can test private or static methods if you compare with Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
public class MyClass {
static class Country{
    public Country(String zipcode){
        onCountryCreated();
    }
    public void onCountryCreated(){

    }
}

@Test
public static void test() {
    Country cntry = new Country("12345"){
        @Override
        public void onCountryCreated(){
            System.out.println("Created");
            //assert true;
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: i am not sure you understand the question. Have changed method name. Have to write an external test case calling methodA("zipvalue"). So we dont have access to the Country Object

Comment: @Rameez Please try to be clear with your questions, I've edited my answer with a possible direction of thought.